# how to dynamically create textboxes by defined variable?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to do something like this : I have a textbox in which I put a number.

When I press enter I save this number in my variable id.
Then I want to create the exact same number of textboxes as my id variable.

It doesn't work because you can't set unknown variable in an array but how could I modify this code to get the result I want?

```
private void tbNbCat_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {         
        int id=0;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Return){
            id = int.Parse(tbNbCat.Text);
            MessageBox.Show(id.ToString());
            createTxtTeamNames(id);
        }
    }

public void createTxtTeamNames(int id)
    {
        TextBox[] txtTeamNames = new TextBox[id];

        for (int u = 0; u < id; u++)  
        {
            txtTeamNames[u] = new TextBox();
        }
        int i = 0;
        foreach (TextBox txt in txtTeamNames)
        {
            string name = "TeamNumber" + i.ToString();

            txt.Name = name;
            txt.Text = name;
            txt.Location = new Point(0, 32 + (i * 28));
            txt.Visible = true;
            this.Controls.Add(txt);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, "can't set unknown variable in an array"?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
 TextBox[] txtTeamNames = new TextBox[id];
```

To

```
 List<TextBox> txtTeamNames = new List<TextBox>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the array in the first place?

```
public void createTxtTeamNames(int id)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < id; ++i)  
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        string name = "TeamNumber" + i.ToString();
        txt.Name = name;
        txt.Text = name;
        txt.Location = new Point(0, 32 + (i * 28));
        txt.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah I should have used a list

Comment: Why use a list?* Why use any container?*